# Install script for private use in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, scripting, bin

I created a script and i want to install it for my private use, i do this steps:

Set execute permission as follows:
`$ chmod 755 demo`

Run it & test it as follows:
`$ ./demo Hello World`

Copy script to your own bin directory (Install script for private use)
`$ cp demo ~/bin`

Check whether it is working or not
`$ demo`
`$ demo Hello World`

But i get this error:
`No command 'demo' found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the `~/bin` path to `$PATH` environment variable so that the shell can find the `demo` executable.

```
$ PATH=$PATH:~/bin
$
```

OR

You can specify the whole path to `demo` executable like this:

`$ ~/bin/demo Hello World`

Comment: how can i add the whole path to demo?

Comment: thanks i found out that i didnt have a bin folder in my home directory